# Colab Pro usually 'Runtime Disconnected'

Tags: google-colaboratory

everyone!
I upgrade my account in Google Colab to Colab Pro today. However, it says 'Runtime Disconnected' when my code runs every time, and it cannot re-connected automatically. But I didn't encounter this problem when I used the normal Colab (not Colab Pro). Could you help me with my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, the reminder 'Runtime Disconnected' usually appears after 3-4 minutes running of my code. The running time does not surpass the limitation of duration of Colab.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: I've the same problem. Pro is a paid subscription and it'll be nice to gain clarity on this. Is there any cap of max up time?